# Hide culture from app id display in toast notification

Tags: c#, notifications, toast, app-id, uiculture

Just had the last hours looking for an answer but couldn't find out, so I have no choice but to ask it.

I have a C# app which pops up toast notification. Within these, I've used "appOverrideLogo" to change the displayed image, so the toast shows the application identity below it's content.

But with application id comes it's culture. Does anyone know a way to hide this last one ?

**Edit :**

[Here is the visual.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oax8r.png)

I'd like to hide "Culture=neutral" at the right of "Application".

Comment: Could you please provide an example of what you're seeing?

Comment: @DanWilson Just edited to show the visual.

Comment: I have never seen that before. What code are you using to build and display the notification?

Comment: Sorry for late answer. 
`var xDoc = new XDocument( new XElement("toast", new XElement("visual",  new XElement("binding", new XAttribute("template", "ToastGeneric"), new XElement("text", "Nouvelle notification"),  ... [content and closing tags];

var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xDoc.ToString());
var toast = new ToastNotification(xmlDoc);`

This builds.
This displays : `ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier(appId.ToString()).Show(toast);`
That's why I don't get it. There's nothing fancy in there.